# I'm trying to identify the manufacturer of this chip

Tags: integrated-circuit

Does anyone recognize this logo?  Just trying to find out who made it.
Thanks

[image: Automotive IC made in Korea]

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Bosch. Is it an ECU by any chance?[image]

(More than you asked for: if you “peel away” the badge and capsule you will find different flavors of Siemens MCUs inside these and the chip is probably manufactured by Infineon)

Comment: Did you know this logo, or some how looked it up?

Comment: @Eugene Knew it. I’ve taken apart enough car electronics to recognize it.

Comment: Bosch logo is everywhere in cars, not only in electronics itself - at least in Europe

Comment: @Ben You are welcome. Feel free to accept my answer so we can “close” this one and move on.

Comment: Didn't see anything that said "is this the answer to your question" but I did see a check mark and clicked it. Hopefully that was it. 